# shouldAutorotate not being called

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to define supported orientations depending on where the user is in my app, I am having a very difficult time doing so.

I have found out thus far that I should use the supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow: and shouldAutorotate methods that are now supported in iOS6, however neither method is ever called where I am defining them in my UIViewController.

This is what my code looks like

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

In my Target Summary Supported Orientatoin I have de-selected all options.. thinking I would just define supported orientation in each of m ViewControllers... I would like to know if this is the correct thing to do?

[image]

Now I have read what I am trying to do is dependant on the structue of my app, so Here I will outline my app.

- main UIViewController (3 buttons taking you to (3 different navigationControllerViews) Wrong! only one navigationController... sorry its been a long time since I looked at this code.)
- secondary UIViewController (holds navigation controller)
- other UIViewControllers (appear in secondarys NavigationController)

I would like every ViewController up untill the last one in the NavigationController stack to appear in portrate. The last view in the NavigationController is a special view that needs to be able to rotate its orientation to left or right if needed.

I would like to know if this is possible and if so why isnt the code that I have above working/being called.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

// Update to question Re:

RootView loads with (three buttons, here is the Method that is called when a button is selected to load the View containing the navigation controller)

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick: (UIButton *) sender
{   
//..

    // v ----->
    if ([sender isEqual:vUIButton]) {


        VSearchViewController *vSearchViewController = [[VSearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VSearchViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vehicalSearchViewController animated:YES];
    }
//..
}
```

Then inside VSearchViewController I load the new views onto the UINavigation stack like this

```
//..
FModelsViewController *fModelsViewController = [[FModelsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FModelsViewController" bundle:nil];

            // Sets the back button for the new view that loads (this overrides the usual parentview name with "Back")
            self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:fModelsViewController animated:YES];
//..
```

So in review I have set up the navigation controller in the appDelegate and all views in my app are on the navigationStack... I was wrong in saying there are 3 NavigationControllers.. there is only one and every view is added to the stack.. Sorry about that.. Its been a year and a half since I looked at this code..

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the above code on iOS6? Those methods will only be called on iOS6.

Also maybe you could post some code to better illustrate how you are transitioning to these viewControllers so we can get a better understanding of the view hierarchy.

You might want to look at UIViewController's `addChildViewController:` method.

Comment: okay, I will post the transition code.. My app is turning into abit of a beast quite a few views due to the complexity of the data I am trying to represent. I will be a couple of minutes with an update to my question.. I will do my best to supply the info you need. (Yes I am deploying to iOS6, Its defined in Targets > iosApplication Target > Deployment Target correct?).

Comment: You need to make sure you are running it on the ios6 simulator. Just because your deployment target is 6 doesn't mean you are running it on 6.

Comment: yup I am running on my ios6 device. Also I have updated with some code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your last view could take advantage of the code written below.  It senses the orientation of the device and will show a different view controller for the landscape view (I'm assuming that is what you are trying to do).  This means your last view will have a portrait and a landscape option.

```
@implementation LastViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                        selector:@selector(orientationLastViewChanged:)
                        name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                        object:nil];
}
- (void)orientationLastViewChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{

UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) &&
!isShowingLandscapeView)
{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LandscapeLastView" sender:self];
isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
}
else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation) &&
    isShowingLandscapeView)
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
isShowingLandscapeView = NO;

}

}
```

on the view controllers leading up to this view that you want locked into portrait, write this code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return NO;
}
```

as for your supported interface orientations, leave that how you have it.

Comment: So what your saying is that the last view would have different .xib files? is that correct?

Comment: Yes but actually my answer assumes you are using storyboards.  Notice the performSegueWithIndetifier method.  This is done in the storyboard.  You would need 2 different view controllers on the storyboard for your last view (one is portrait and one is landscape).  You would have a segue linking the portrait to the landscape and another linking the landscape to the portrait.

Comment: right.. Unfortunatly this method wont work for me (I know selfish right! lol).. My last view is so intricit that I imagin it would be almost impossible to get this to work inside the time I have allowed without rewriting that view... but thankyou very much for your answer I will look into it more if it turns out its the only way to achive the result I am after.